# Is there a way to improve performance of adding unsigned long long to unsigned int

Tags: c++, performance, unsigned-integer

Is there a way to improve performance of adding unsigned long long to unsigned int ?

I'm looping multiple times and have to do a sum of this type :

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 320000000; ++i)
{
unsigned long long myUlonglong = 123456;
unsigned long long ret = i + myUlonglong;
//do some other stuff here with ret
}
```

If myUlonglong and ret are `unsigned long long` the operation takes much more time than if they are `unsigned int`. Is there a way to improve it ? And why is it longer ?

The types are mandatory, i must use unsigned long long.
I'm on x86_64, with gcc 6.4.1, and no specific option for g++

***EDIT***

My code looks like that more than the fisrt example :

```
typedef struct {
unsigned long long start;
unsigned int duration;
} info;


#define EPSILON 200

std::list<info> listInfoA; // 200 000 elements here
std::list<info> listInfoB; // 200 000 elements here

std::list<info>::iterator indInfoB = infoB.begin();
std::list<info>::iterator endInfoB = infoB.end();

for(auto &infoA:listInfoA)
{
    const unsigned long long endInfoA = infoA.start + infoA.duration;
    
    keepGoing = true;
    while(keepGoing && indInfoB != endInfoB)
    {
        info &refInfoB = *indInfoB;
        
        if(endInfoA < refInfoB.start + refInfoB.duration + EPSILON)
        {
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please pick one language, not two. How long is "long" ? How did you measure it?

Comment: The code you posted will be optimized away to nothing. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Y4d7edfaM

Comment: details matter. As Ayxan pointed out, one can only discuss runtime of this in a meaningful way when `//do some other stuff` is actually doing something

Comment: And if you loop over `(ret = 123456; ret < 320123456; ret++)` and do without the intermediate `i`? (But a modern optimizing compiler will probably see such things.)

Comment: What was your `g++` command line?  How did you measure the performance?

Comment: I have a hard time believing `do some other stuff here with ret` is somehow less expensive than adding two numbers together. You may be focusing on the wrong thing here.

Comment: again: details do matter. Your updated code is a whole different story than the first. Not sure whats the best as you already got answers, but the new code is a complete rewrite of the quesiton rather than an add on. Maybe open a new question where you ask the question you acutally wanted to ask, and include details on your benchmark

Comment: A `std::list` is about, if the not the worst data structure to iterate through.  That alone is going to kill all performance that you might gain by micro-optimizing your code.

Comment: the elephant in the room is " the operation takes much more time than if they are unsigned int" I am clueless how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: In the updated code, the compiler leverages pointer arithmetic operations in order to collapse the whole thing as a single instruction, you'll be hard pressed to beat it: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3EhWG6vMK. Just retrieving the values from the entries is going to be by far the most expensive part of the operation.

Comment: switch those lists for vectors if possible... reserve them big if you know theyll be big.

Answer (score 1):

A good compiler will optimize away the addition you mentioned and simply count from `123456` to `320123456`. If we call a function `foo` with `ret` to avoid everything begin completely optimized away, here's what GCC 11 generates:

```
main:
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 123456
.L2:
        mov     rdi, rbx
        add     rbx, 1
        call    foo(unsigned long long)
        cmp     rbx, 320123456
        jne     .L2
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

You can see that there is no `unsigned long long` and `unsigned int` addition is going on. You can't optimize something more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited my question to be more specific about my real problem

Comment: @Saya if you're iterating `std::list` there, I doubt you're going to get any benefit from optimizing an addition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily going to be any faster given a good optimiser, but you can at least simplify the program:

```
unsigned long long begin = 123456;
unsigned long long end = 320000000 + begin;
for(auto ret = begin; ret < end; ++ret)
{
    //do some other stuff here with ret
}
```

---

> EDIT
>
> My code looks like that more than the fisrt example :

You're iterating linked lists. The additions are going to be a drop in the bucket compared to that. You'd be wasting your time trying to optimise the addition.

Answer (score 0):

First requirement of fast code: turn on optimizations.  This requires a release rather than debug build.

There are several ways to improve performance for an operation with determinate results.  The fastest of which is likely to build a gigantic lookup table stored in memory.

In your case above though (assuming you really really want unsigned long long instead of the nicer more explicit uint64_t), I'd simply change the for loop to read:

```
const unsigned long long myUlonglong = 123456;
for(unsigned long long ret=myUlonglong + 0; ret < myUlonglong + 320000000; ++ret)
{
//do some other stuff here with ret
}
```

In addition if your "other stuff" does not need to be performed in order and you have more cores that happen to be idle, you can burn more cpu instead of memory and attempt some multi-threading.  Task each thread with some fraction of your other stuff calls.